# p12 (PKCS#12) certificat convert to DER fails using OpenSSL

Tags: ios, objective-c, certificate, pkcs#12, der

Dose somebody had a luck converting p12 crt to DER? What I am doing wrong?

Convert p12 to DER I am using **i2d_PKCS12_bio**. To get ref to certificate I am using **SecCertificateCreateWithData()** method which returns nil. This method is taking only DER data as written in the Apple doc.

In [OpenSSL documentations](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSL/OpenSSL-7.1/openssl/doc/openssl.txt) is written:

> **i2d**       is the standard ASN1 function that converts the internal
>         structure into the DER representation: for example
>         i2d_ASN1_IA5STRING().

```
PKCS12 *p12; // p12 was created ok.
char *data_p12 = NULL;
BIO *mem = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
i2d_PKCS12_bio(mem, p12); // In the documentation is written that data should be converted to DER.
int _flush __attribute__((unused)) = BIO_flush(mem);
long size = BIO_get_mem_data(mem, &data_p12);
NSData *retData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:data_p12 length:size];

CFDataRef dataRef = CFDataCreate(nil, retData.bytes, retData.length);
SecCertificateRef secRef = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, dataRef);
// secRef is nil. FAIL!
```

PS: I did save p12 data as file and it work as p12 file.